# How does the search.list YouTube API work with relevanceLanguage and date filtering?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API to retrieve videos for a specific 1 hour time slot, with relevanceLanguage set to "uk" and ordered by date. There is no query term ("q" parameter) and I expect to see all videos relevant to the "uk" language but I am only receiving 250-350 videos in total, even though there are likely more videos posted within the hour that are relevant to the language.

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=date&publishedAfter=2023-01-29T11:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2023-01-29T12:00:00Z&relevanceLanguage=uk&type=video&key={{apiKey}}
```

> The relevanceLanguage parameter instructs the API to return search results that are most relevant to the specified language (according to documentation)

I'm aware that there is a limitation of 500 videos per search. That's why I have 1 hour timeslot to bypass it.
All videos returned are equally distributed within the timeslot (publishedAt field).
There are also videos with just a few views (1-10). I do believe that there are way more videos posted within an hour relevant for a specific language. I've tried to find a few videos manually posted within that timeslot and they were not listed in my search api response.

**Is it correct to assume that the search.list API only returns videos chosen by the YouTube recommendation algorithm for this specific language and can be treated as a representative sample of what are people interested to watch?.  **

Comment: As far as I know the limitation mentioned on YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint for the [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) filter applies more broadly.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Thanks. Yes, there is a limitation of 500 videos per search. That's why I have 1 hour timeslot to bypass it. But anyway using channelId filter will return videos for 1 specific channel only while I need to get all channels/videos relevant for specific language

Comment: I just verified again and I confirm that trying to bypass the limitation of 500 videos per search isn't doable with using [`publishedBefore`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedBefore) and [`publishedAfter`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter). In my opinion YouTube Data API v3 is suffering a lot of bugs, so don't consider the returned results as representative.

Comment: @BogdanKolodii `I do believe that there are way more videos posted within an hour relevant for a specific language` - yes, however, I can't tell if YouTube uses the country/region set in the channel's info for decide if a video is relevant/belongs to certain region and not every channel has this info added. As Benjamin Loison mentioned, YouTube API has a lot of bugs. You could post the issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) - or see if someone else has this same problem - and see an official response there.